# What is the proper way to notify user that object has changed in MVVM + EntityFramework?

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm

For example, if you want to have a visual cue like the red dot in Visual Studio next to each document with pending changes, what's the usual way to implement it using MVVM where the model is an entity framework model? Do you just keep an IsDirty flag at the view model level? I'm guessing you don't want to keep calling DetectChanges in your db context to see if the entity has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If your model object implements INotifyPropertyChange, you can always tap PropertyChanged event. Given that you check for the properties being set to the same value, e.g.:

```
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        if(_name == value) return;
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

You can observe if *any* property on your model is changed from your ViewModel and show/hide that Icon via a flag on the ViewModel, something along the lines of:

```
public class TreeItemViewModel
{
    public TreeViewModel(TreeItem model)
    {
        model.PropertyChanged += OnTreeItemModified();
    }

    private void OnTreeItemModified(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DisplayIcon = true;
    }
}
```